# Authenticating Cloud Functions URLs for Google Pubsub push in same project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have HTTP Cloud Function and I would like to use it as the Google PubSub Push endpoint. Cloud Function, Topic and Subscriber all are in the same project.

As per the [link](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#authenticating_standard_and_urls) I can use something like `/_ah/push-handlers/.*` with the Cloud Function URL and it should work but I am unable to find any example of how to use this with Cloud Function.

I already know the other way i.e. I need to do Site Verification & Domain Verification but to me this sounds really stupid when both the Cloud Function and PubSub are in the same project.

Can some one put some light on this. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

`/_ah/push-handlers/.*` is only a requirement for App Engine, not for Cloud Functions. As the [documentation says](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#authenticating_standard_and_urls):

> The mechanism is similar for Cloud Functions, but does not require any particular path.